# Is it possible to program ATtiny85 with ch340?

Tags: attiny85

I'm thinking to build a PCB for programming ATtiny85 (in Arduino IDE) with ch340. Can I use this schematic?

[image: Schematic]

([Source](https://cdn.hackaday.io/files/293271254726368/nano_ch340_schematics-rev1.pdf))

Answer (score 0):

No. At least not without already having some Arduino compatible or otherwise UART capable bootloader being programmed into the Tiny85.

So you need an ISP programmer anyway to program anything you want like a bootloader to an empty Tiny85 before you can use the bootloader to upload firmare without ISP programmer.

Comment: Can use CP210x?

Comment: Same applies to all USB UART ICs. Unless they are capable of bit-banging the ISP interface, and you have some programming software that supports using some USB UART IC in bit-banging mode to do ISP. But then you can't use those schematics either. Did you know you can use an Arduino as an ISP programmer? If you already have an Arduino you don't need to build any programmer.

Comment: Yes I know. But I want to do a minimal pcb for specifically programming ATtiny25/45/85. Will I need atmega16u2/32u4? In my country it's very expensive. There are cheap chip for ISP?

Answer (score 0):

Programming AVR needs some sort of parallel IO port, FT232, or USBasp, or a cheap Arduino Uno clone are probably the cheapest options. unless you have a copmputer with an actual parallel port.

Comment: ISP is parallel? FT232 is USB to UART and USBasp uses ATmega8 or '88.

Comment: FT232 is much more than that.